# Google One tap sign-in UI not displayed in incognito mode in chrome V8 or firefox (gsi library in angular)

Tags: angular, google-signin, google-one-tap

Hello I'm using the Google one tap sign in ui but when in incognito mode (all cookie enabled) this is not displayed and nothing is happening. this is my code

```
//@ts-ignore
google.accounts.id.initialize({
    client_id: environment.googleAuthClientId,
    callback: (window as any)['handleCredentialResponse'] =
    (response: any) => this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.user = response;
      this.loggedIn = response != null;
      localStorage.setItem(LocalStorageKeyEnum.USER, JSON.stringify(response.credential));
      this.checkPermission();
    })
});
```

I've already try this code below as workaround in firefox and it works, but doesn't work in chrome or edge.

```
google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => {
     if (notification.isNotDisplayed() || notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
         document.cookie =  "g_state=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
             google.accounts.id.prompt()
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with React. For incognito mode, apart from resetting the g_state cookie as suggested above, you will have to trigger login through window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient if one step fails.
so essentially there needs to be another flow triggered for case

`if (notification.isNotDisplayed() && notification.getNotDisplayedReason() === "opt_out_or_no_session") { window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient() **with all the goodies that function needs** }`

Here is an example that works for incognito https://books-rtk.vercel.app(works as in not for onestep login but login through the second way if 1-step fails), it's in React/RTK query but the flow may help.
the GAuth login flow is in file https://github.com/marciamoss/books_rtk/blob/main/src/store/apis/authApi.js